# Crosstab crystal report visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I’m building an application in which it generates a report in cross-tab format using asp.net environment in visual studio IDE. My question is; do you’ve any idea how to convert the direction of the report from left-right to be right to left “arabic and hebrew” content.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Preferred Viewing Locale from Crystal Reports designer:

Open Crystal Reports designer.

Under the menu ***View***, select ***Preferred Viewing Locale***

Select the desired language. And close Crystal Reports.

Note: The change of the Preferred Viewing Locale will be save into Registry Key, for the specific user:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\LanguageOptions

Comment: It doesn’t work with visual studio